# Meaning of "ETC" in FORMATETC and "TYMED"?

Tags: windows, winapi, com, naming-conventions, naming

I feel uncomfortable when I need to use names in the code that I don't fully understand. Currently I want to implement clipboard functionality with OLE and I've encountered a bit confusing `FORMATETC` and `TYMED`. Sadly, I can't find explanation on Microsoft Docs. What is "ETC"? Is that "et cetera"? If so, it seems to be a bad name. And `TYMED`? "MED" most likely means "medium", but what is "TY"?

Comment: tymed is probably type of (storage) medium. In hungarian notation, you could use a prefix that meant something (very unlike dwAspect because dw for DWORD means nothing beyond the fact it's a dwORD). ETC is lost in time (Enhanced Target Clipboard?). These probably date Windows 1.0 (1985 or so).

Comment: They couldn't use words like format, type, media without risking identifier name collisions.  Generous amounts of beer solved the problem.  Very little of what that group released in 1994 (project Chicago) is still in common use today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear, indeed, that the "etc" part of `FORMATETC` stands for *et cetera* (Latin for *"and so on,"* or *"and the rest"*), as the [`FORMATETC` structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/ns-objidl-formatetc) contains a member specifying the **format type** along with members specifying 'other' information:

```cpp
typedef struct tagFORMATETC {
  CLIPFORMAT     cfFormat;
  DVTARGETDEVICE *ptd;
  DWORD          dwAspect;
  LONG           lindex;
  DWORD          tymed;
} FORMATETC, *LPFORMATETC;
```

The `TYMED` [enumeration values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/ne-objidl-tymed) do (also as you have postulated) represent different **TY**pes of storage **MED**ia.

Comment: There is also a suggestion in the comments that "ETC is Enhanced Target Clipboard".

Comment: But I think that you may be right on that. Though I don't like this kind of naming. Unsatisfying.